# React element - array objects only returning first item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, reactjs

I am trying to retrieve item values from an object containing several items. The object is an array object. I am puzzled by only being able to retrive the first item and its values in each array instead of all items. Can anybody tell me what I am missing here.

#### The array object example:

```
{ "ITEM 1": [
 {
   "id": 123,
   "name": "item1a"
 },
 {
   "id": 234,
   "name": "item1b"
 },
 {
   "id": 345,
   "name": "item1c"
 }
],
"ITEM 2": [
{
  "id": 456,
  "name": "item2a"
},
{
  "id": 567,
  "name": "item2b"
},
{
  "id": 678,
  "name": "item2c"
}],
}
```

I have data within the new element and on debugging see that loop flows correctly but for some reason only the first item is rendered.

#### My code that is wrapped in an html element is as follows:

```
  { Object.keys(this.props.data).map(function (key) {
     var list = component.props.data[key];
     for (i = 0; i < facetParent.length; i++) {
       var item = list[i];
       return ( 
           <CheckBox
               key={item.id}
               data={item}
               name={item.name} />
              )
         }}, this)}
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The return function immediately terminates the function execution. That is why you only get the first item. Depending on what version of react you use, you should create 2 arrays and join them before rendering